# Dynamically update a buttons onclick inside a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to pass a value into a Bootstrap Modal and then display it when a button is clicked, however nothing is displaying when I click the button.. Can anyone help fix the issue?

I believe the issue is on the line:

```
$(e.currentTarget).find('button[id="save"]').onclick = function() { alert(id); };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9m13c4rx/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('button[id="save"]').onclick = function() { alert(id); };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) is a vanilla JavaScript property for processing *click* events on a given element, but you are trying to implement that on a jQuery object, use jQuery's [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) instead.

**Update:**  The best solution is to write the button click event outside the modal event handler function.

```
$('#save').click(function() { alert(id); });
```

If you still want the code to be inside the modal event then you can use flag variable based on which you can execute the button click event.

```js
var flag = false; // set the flag to false
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  if(!flag){ // check the flag
    $(e.currentTarget).find('button[id="save"]').click(function() { alert(id); });
    flag = true; // set the flag to true
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AK47, If you are not bound to write the button click event outside the modal event handler function then you writing that outside the modal event will solve the issue. I have updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 2):

i have fixed your code

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $("#save").click(function(){
   alert(id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```